# Nodes и fps при запуске

Tags: xcode, swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске приложения в углу показывается nodes и fps, а как их убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас где то (во ViewController?) есть такие строки

```
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
```

удалите